# Prevent EGLContext to be destroyed when going to background

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, glsurfaceview, onpause

My Android (OpenGL ES 2.0) game needs to be paused when user is minimizing it, without destroying what is already drawn on screen. Originally it used NativeActivity and pure C++, but it looks like it is not possible there. I have rewritten it and it is now Java generating custom GLSurfaceView and game logic+rendering is in C++. I added *setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true)* when surface is created.

So the flaw after user click Home button is:

1. *onPause* is sending *nativeOnPause* to C++ code through JNI
2. C++ code sets pause variable which prevents updating and rendering

This works ok. After we get back to app:

1. *onResume* calls *nativeOnResume*
2. nativeOnResume calls EGL methods to get current context, display and surface and pass that to game manager.
3. Updating and rendering is now activated
4. We get few *EGL_BAD_SURFACE* messages and finally crash on *eglMakeCurrent*

The question is: should we in any way recreate EGLSurface and EGLDisplay using current context, or getting current surface and display is fine?

I also noticed that when we get back to app, *onResume* is called, but *onSurfaceChanged* or *onSurfaceCreated* is not called.

Any suggestion how to approach that problem on >4.0 devices?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use GLSurfaceView if you want to control the EGL context lifetime.

The GLSurfaceView class handles the EGL context for you, and is fairly aggressive about discarding it. The `setPreserveEGLContextOnPause()` call probably won't do what you want. If you switch to a SurfaceView you will have full control over the EGL context lifetime, but that's a double-edged sword, as you are now required to manage the EGL context entirely.

You can find various examples of using GLES with SurfaceView in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/).  The "[hardware scaler exerciser](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/HardwareScalerActivity.java)" activity is a reasonable example.

That activity also demonstrates one approach to Activity lifecycle management.  A discussion of the relationship between Activity and SurfaceView, including why you're not always seeing `surfaceChanged()` and `surfaceCreated()`, can be found [in an appendix](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity) to the graphics architecture document.

Having said all that, keeping the EGL context and all associated resources around while your app is inactive is a bad practice.  When the user pauses your app, those resources should be released so that other apps have the full capabilities of the device at their disposal.